# Firebase Realtime Database Issues

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

i have a simple website where user enters some details and a card is generated on a next page with a number that is taken from realtime database of firebase that is where i'm stuck.

the problem is when ever I try to get value from firebase nothing happens and I don't even get any errors or warnings either. same happens when I try to update value using the increment function no errors no warnings.

my code

```
import { getDatabase, ref, increment, child, get, update } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.0.0/firebase-database.js'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxx"
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase(app);

function UpdatePassNumber() {
    const dbRef = ref(db);

    var updates = {
        CurrentPassNumber : increment(1)
    };

    update(dbRef, updates).then(() => {
        alert("Data saved successfully.");
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
function GatherData() {

    if (!navigator.onLine) {
        console.log('You are offline');
    }

    get(child(ref(getDatabase()), `GatePassNumber/CurrentPassNumber`)).then((snapshot) => {
        console.log("got here");
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            console.log(snapshot.val() + " From Here");
        } else {
            console.log("No data available");
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Get Error : " + error);
    });

    
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening or why isn't anything happening.

I tried checking console log to see where am i getting stuck but nothing at all both functions are getting executed from start to finish.

I also waited for 10 to 15 min for response but nothing.

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, and "nothing happens" is unfortunately really hard to help with. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: If what you're showing here is a complete program, I'll point out that there are no calls to either `UpdatePassNumber` or `GatherData`, so none of their code are being run.  It's a good idea to provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) that anyone can copy and run for themselves.

Comment: they are bound to buttons

Comment: also when i first click the button i get a warning that says missing app check token and then no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figured it out

1. app check was enforced on my realtime database so unverified requests were getting rejected hence no errors
2. i set up a debug token for my app and now its working fine.